# swift sequenceType return nil

Tags: swift, sequence

My object conforms to the SequenceType, so it implements the generate function.
My object has an optional object which has an array of values
If I have an array I return the values via a generator, but if there are no values the generator has to return nil. I have the code below which works but it's rather verbose. Is there a nicer way to handle this?

```
func generate() -> GeneratorOf<ValueType> {
    if let values = self.data.values
    {
        var index : Int = 0
        return GeneratorOf<ValueType> {
            return (index < values.count) ? values[index++] : nil
        }
    }
    //how to improve these lines (or wrap it into the code above?) This feels like repetition.
    return GeneratorOf<ValueType> { 
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an optional generator from your optional `values`.  Then use optional chaining to call `next`:

```
func generate() -> GeneratorOf<ValueType> {
    var g = data.values?.generate()
    return GeneratorOf<ValueType> {
        return g?.next()
    }
}
```

If the generator is `nil`, it’ll just return `nil` on first call, otherwise it’ll return all the vales in `values`.